# React Native button map for a button group

Tags: javascript, css, button, react-native

Trying to figure out how to change the styling on just the first and last button. 
How do I tell the button which one is which? 
Beginner in JS and React/React Native trying to find my way. Currently coming out with no rounded buttons on either end.
 The Button element in the child is my own wrapper on TouchableOpacity and only accepts an object for the buttonStyles. 
Any help appreciated.

Parent component:

```
export class Rating extends React.Component {

  ratings = [
    { text: '1' },
    { text: '2' },
    { text: '3' },
    { text: '4' },
    { text: '5' },
  ];

  onButtonPress = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.ratings.length && (
          this.ratings.map((rating, index) => (
            <View key={index}>
              <RatingButton rating={rating} onButtonPress={this.onButtonPress} />
            </View>
          ))
        )
      }
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
const buttonStyles = () => {
  const allButtons = {
    backgroundColor: sc.colors.white.white,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: sc.colors.blue.darker1,
    padding: sc.padding.lg,
  };

  const startButton = {
    borderTopLeftRadius: sc.borderRadius.sm,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: sc.borderRadius.sm,
    borderRightWidth: 0.75,
    ...allButtons,
  };

  const endButton = {
    borderTopRightRadius: sc.borderRadius.sm,
    borderBottomRightRadius: sc.borderRadius.sm,
    borderLeftWidth: 0.75,
    ...allButtons,
  };
  return StyleSheet.create({
    allButtons,
    startButton,
    endButton,
    buttonText: {
      color: sc.colors.blue.darker1,
      fontSize: sc.font.size.largeContent,
    },
  });
};

class RatingButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { onButtonPress, rating } = this.props;
    const styles = buttonStyles();
    return (
      <Button
        buttonStyles={styles.allButtons}
        textStyles={styles.buttonText}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
      >
        {rating.text}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `ratings` variable, you could store another attribute for style like so:

```
ratings = [
    { text: '1', style: {backgroundColor:'red'} },
    { text: '2' },
    { text: '3' },
    { text: '4' },
    { text: '5', backgroundColor: 'yellow' },
  ];
```

And then inside of `<RatingButton/>` you can add the style to the element

```
<Button
        buttonStyles={styles.allButtons}
        textStyles={styles.buttonText}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
        style={rating.style}
      >
        {rating.text}
</Button>
```

Note: You could also pass a class through the `rating` variable.

```
ratings = [
    { text: '1', buttonStyle: 'startButton' },
    { text: '2' },
    { text: '3' },
    { text: '4' },
    { text: '5', buttonStyle: 'endButton' },
  ];
```

and set your style like this:

```
<Button
        buttonStyles={ratings.buttonStyle?styles[rating.buttonStyle]:styles.allButtons}
        textStyles={styles.buttonText}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
        style={rating.style}
      >
        {rating.text}
</Button>
```

Comment: oh that does work! Is there a way to make it not so specific to the button in the ratings array? So if more buttons were added it would always do the first and last button?

Comment: I was thinking of something like

`generateButtons = () => {
    return this.ratings.map((rating, index) => {
      const buttonType = 'startButton';

      if (index === 0) {

      }
    });
  }`

but cant seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: I actually figured it out!

Comment: With `Array.map` you can access the index, so when `index==0` you can use the start button and if it is in the last index you can use the end button style. Passing it in through props will allow for more flexibility (different kind of button styles).

Comment: Do you know how I can the onButtonPress function to work? It is not currently logging out anything.

Comment: take a look at the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html). You probably are looking for `<button onPress={event=>{/*Your code*/}}/>` I believe.